# Why doesn't scala inline factory methods for value classes?

Tags: scala, inline, value-class

Consider:

```
class Wrap(val amount :Int) extends AnyVal

object Wrap {
    @inline final def apply(int :Int) = new Wrap(int)
}

object Playground {
    val w = Wrap(1)
}
```

compiling with (2.11.7) `scalac -feature -Xprint:all Playground.scala` I see

```
Playground.this.w = Wrap.apply(1);
```

and indeed, `javap -v -private Playground` shows:

```
    89: invokevirtual #75                 // Method Wrap$.apply:(I)I
    92: putfield      #33                 // Field w:I
```

When changing Playground constructor to:

```
val w = new Wrap(1)
```

both show assignment of literal `1` to `w` as expected. I am frankly quite dissapointed with this discovery, as it practically prevents type-level programming using value classes (where an ephemeric value class instance is created by a chain of trivial inlined methods.